# How can I make this container with buttons more responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to make `div.box` and `button.navBtn` responsive.

Currently when the page is resized to 871px width, the buttons instantly stack on top of each other and the long `div.box` is squished until it clashes into the buttons. The "final look" (around 500px wide) doesn't even look that bad honestly and is the ideal way this window would look on smaller screens. I'm just trying to make the transition to that size nicer.

Preferably I'd like the buttons to resize themselves gradually with `div.box` until they hit a certain width and then stack on top of each other however I can't figure out how to apply the correct media query to do this. I feel as if my divider is causing some type of issue a well with spacing but I'm not entirely sure. It does have some whitespace I can't get rid of and is set to 2em width.

I'm also not sure why `div.main` stops resizing once you hit around 495px width. I'm gonna make sure I use Bootstrap or something next time to avoid this...

Any help would be appreciated. Here's a big snippet of code:

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    margin: .8em;
    background-color: #151b20;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
    color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
    color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

a {
    color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
    color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

button {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url(Pictures/blank.png);
    color: #a5afaa;
    border: 3.5px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .6em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /* transition: all 0.2s; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

button:hover {
    border-color: #fff8cc;
    box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0em #fff8cc;
    cursor: url('Pictures/glove-lg.png'), auto;
}

.main {
    border: solid 2px #939388;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url(Pictures/texture.png);
    background-color: #0f0f3de8;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.decoration {
    outline: 2px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4);
    outline-offset: -5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.box {
    background-color: #080824;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navHome {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.navBtn {
    border: solid 2px #939388;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #0f0f3d;
    width: 25em;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navText {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    line-height: 0em;
}

.divider {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    height: auto;
}

.aboutText {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#about {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#homeList {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#homeBox {
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="decoration">
                <div id="about">
                    <h1>I mean, it kinda works...</h1>
                    <ul id="homeList">
                        <li>Long List Item #1</li>
                        <li>Long List Item #2</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="innerHome" class="inner">
                        <div id="homeBox" class="box">
                            <a href="" class="navHome">
                                <button class="navBtn">
                                    <div class="navText">About</div>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <a href="" class="navHome">
                                <button class="navBtn">
                                    <div class="navText">Items</div>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the buttons to resize themselves you can't give them an explicit width like you do in `.navBtn`. You need to make them have a certain percentage of the parent and when they hit their minimal witdh they wrap.
Without that change the best that can be done is making the parent smaller when the elements wrap like so:

```css
#homeBox {
  width: min-content;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #homeBox {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  margin: .8em;
  background-color: #151b20;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

h2 {
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

a {
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url(Pictures/blank.png);
  color: #a5afaa;
  border: 3.5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .6em;
  padding: 2.8em;
  /* transition: all 0.2s; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #fff8cc;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0em #fff8cc;
  cursor: url('Pictures/glove-lg.png'), auto;
}

.main {
  border: solid 2px #939388;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url(Pictures/texture.png);
  background-color: #0f0f3de8;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.decoration {
  outline: 2px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4);
  outline-offset: -5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.box {
  background-color: #080824;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navHome {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navBtn {
  border: solid 2px #939388;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #0f0f3d;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  /* max-width: 25em; */
  width: 25em;
}

.navText {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  line-height: 0em;
}

.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: auto;
}

.aboutText {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#about {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#homeList {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#homeBox {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#homeBox {
  width: min-content;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #homeBox {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="decoration">
        <div id="about">
          <h1>I mean, it kinda works...</h1>
          <ul id="homeList">
            <li>Long List Item #1</li>
            <li>Long List Item #2</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="innerHome" class="inner">
            <div id="homeBox" class="box">
              <a href="" class="navHome">
                <button class="navBtn">
                  <div class="navText">About</div>
                </button>
              </a>
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <a href="" class="navHome">
                <button class="navBtn">
                  <div class="navText">Items</div>
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```